# How to draw voronoi diagram from a json with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, html, d3.js, voronoi

```
Drawing voronoi diagram from a json  with d3.js and show the names in the center of each box where the black dots are shown.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366




<script>   
var width = 900,
    height = 500;


var vertices=[
              [200, 200],
              [760, 300],
              [230, 380],
              [660, 800],
              [660, 500],
              [660, 800],
              [160, 800],
              [460, 800],
              [860, 200],
              [660, 800],
              [760, 600],
              [260, 800],
              [660, 600]
            ];

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .clipExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

var svg = d3.select("#Voronoi").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mousemove", function() { vertices[0] = d3.mouse(this); redraw(); });

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path");
var text1 = svg.append("svg:text");

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(vertices.slice(1))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; })
    .text(width);
    .attr("r", 1.5);
redraw();

function redraw() {
  path = path
      .data(voronoi(vertices), polygon);

  path.exit().remove();

  path.enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "q" + (i % 9) + "-9"; })
      .attr("d", polygon);

  path.order();
}

function polygon(d) {
  return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
} 
</script>
```

Above is my script. I am generating diagram using the points in vertices. How to generate such a thing using json. But the json contains the points and name of each box. The name should be show on each box.

Comment: So the question is - how to label the clusters near their centers?

Comment: Not the cluster, each box where the black dots are shown. Also i want to know how to draw the diagram using json.

Comment: could you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727925/trying-to-modify-voronoi-map-in-d3js ?, may be there is some information which could help you to get further. P.S. by cluster I meant - a cell with a dot in it's center